# Сan't set custom sound and vibration for notifications on Android Oreo+

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I can't set custom notification sound and vibration pattern for android oreo and above. For earlier versions of android everything works as it should. I wrote my code based on these answers:
[Custom notification sound , android Oreo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029659/custom-notification-sound-android-oreo),
[Custom Notification Sound not working in Android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567164/custom-notification-sound-not-working-in-android-oreo)
and others.
But none of this had the desired result.
The notification comes, but without sound and vibration. The values of isSoundEnabled and isVibrationEnabled are transmitted correctly.

My method:

```
   private void sendNotif(String title, String text, boolean isSoundEnabled, boolean isVibrationEnabled) {

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        String channelName = "EEE";
        String channelId = "CHANNEL_1";
        long[] vibrationPattern = new long[]{40, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 750};
        long[] vibrationEmpty = new long[]{0};
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.notification);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityOne.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setContentText(text)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            channel.enableLights(true);

            if (isSoundEnabled) {
                AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes
                        .Builder()
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                        .build();
                channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
            } else {
                channel.setSound(null, null);
            }

            channel.enableVibration(isVibrationEnabled);

            if (isVibrationEnabled){
                channel.setVibrationPattern(vibrationPattern);
            } else {
                channel.setVibrationPattern(vibrationEmpty);
            }
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            builder.setChannelId(channelId);


        } else {

            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelName)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(text)
                    .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent);

            if (isSoundEnabled) {
                builder.setSound(soundUri);
            }
            if (isVibrationEnabled) {
                builder.setVibrate(vibrationPattern);
            } else {
                builder.setVibrate(vibrationEmpty);
            }
        }

        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(10000), builder.build());
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that a `NotificationChannel` is write-once; you cannot modify it once it is created. You may wish to fully uninstall and reinstall your app, then see if your channel works better.

Comment: @CommonsWare, It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. The checks `if (isSoundEnabled)` and  `if (isVibrationEnabled)` were unnecessary. To control vibration and notification sounds on android oreo+, you need to create separate channels.

Comment: Absolutely correct @bruno13, Channel Id used for notification builder and notification channel has to be a different id than other channel Id. Thanks.